# backup Hashicorp Vault server and use the backup to build new server

Tags: hashicorp-vault

We are using Hashicorp Vault with Consul as storage, we want to implement a robust backup and recovery strategy for vault.

we are particularly looking to backup all the Vault data and use that file as storage while building new vault server.

I did enough research, not able to find a convincing solution:(

Please provide any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This is **what we followed in our production environment for the high availability of the Vault server**.

- As your using Consul as backend, **make sure Consul/backend is highly available as all the data/secrets are stored in it**.

Just to check the behavior, try **running vault server with two instances** but pointing to same backend, consul. Observe that **both the instances**, when UI opened from the browser, **points the same data** as the backend is same.

When **Vault is backed by a persistent/high available storage**, **Vault can be considered just as front-end/UI service** which display data/secrets/policies.

Answer (score 2):

[Vault High Availability with Consul](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/operations/ops-vault-ha-consul) that is what was Here_2_learn talking about.

Also, if you using Consul as a storage backend for Vault, you can use the [consul snapshot](https://www.consul.io/docs/commands/snapshot.html) for backing up our data.